# How to disable auto indentation in qt xml

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am trying to Edit an xml file in which some tags are properly intended , but some are not. This done for good readability . But when editing this document with QDomDocument , the file is auto formatted and lost default settings . Is there any way to disable auto formatting or specify separate indentation/formatting for each tag

eg

```
<root>
    <sub1><inner1>fdgf</inner1><sub1>
    <sub2><inner2>fdgf</inner2><sub2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QDomDocument::toString` with `indent = -1`.

[Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html#toString)